# using google map api v3 but map split into squares

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3 to create a map. While I am using it into my web page, I see the map split into squares. Before, I was using that code in another web page and ui working well. I can't find the problem.

See this picture: http://uphinh.ssc.vn/images/205Untitled.png

code:

```
<div id="infomation" style="height:35%;">
        <div id="map" style="width:66%; height:99.5%; float:left">

        </div>
        <div id="myinfo" style="width:33.4%;height: 99.5%; float:left">
            <p id="mylocation"></p>
            <button id="changeMyLocation" onClick="changeMyLocation()">Change</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope someone can help me find the error.

Comment: That is a css problem.  css borders are getting applied to all the images on the map (looks like).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check in your css for #map div {}

Your div borders are being propegated. I think possibly a

```
#map div div {border:0}
```

might fix your issue.

EDIT
Always supposing you called your map container #map and not #map_container or something else.